# Thread memory usage keeps increasing

Tags: python, multithreading, memory

I am trying to visit the webpages and check if the website owner allows to contact him or not..

Here is http://pastebin.com/12rLXQaz

This is the function that each thread calls:

```
def getpage():
    try:
        curl = urls.pop(0)
        print "working on " +str(curl)
        thepage1 = requests.get(curl).text
        global ctot
        if "Contact Us" in thepage1:
            slist.write("\n" +curl)
            ctot = ctot + 1
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        if len(urls)>0 :
            getpage()
```

But the thing is memory of program keep on getting increased..  (pythonw.exe)

As the thread calling the function again the condition is true .. the memory of the program should stay at least approximately at the same level.

For a list containing about 100k URLs, the program is taking much more than 3GB and increasing...

Comment: Have you tried to put them into a `queue.Queue` and only start 100 threads? Or starting max 100 threads and then starting to `join()`

Comment: haven't tried  Queue.. if i use join in the function the program waits until all threads gets completed which takes much more time

Comment: 1. Try to include the relevant bits for your code in your question. 2. Your code doesn't work, "NameError: name 'tarray' is not defined".

Comment: ah.. edited that.. check now : http://pastebin.com/12rLXQaz

Comment: Your `ctot`, `slist` usage is not thread-safe. You could move it to the main thread, [example](https://gist.github.com/776b0ef21c118aedbdd1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is recursive for no reason. The recursion means that for each page you get you create a new set of variables, and since these are still being referenced by the local variables in the function, since the function never ends, the garbage collection never comes into play, and it will continue to eat memory for ever.

Read up on the [`while`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) statement, it's the one you want to use instead of recursion here.

```
while len(urls)>0 :
    try:
        curl = urls.pop(0)
        thepage1 = requests.get(curl).text
        global ctot
        if "Contact Us" in thepage1:
            slist.write("\n" +curl)
            ctot = ctot + 1
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a look at your code: http://pastebin.com/J4Rd3NhA

I would use join while 100 threads run:

```
for xd in range(0,noofthreads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=getpage)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    tarray.append(t)
    # my additional code
    if len(tarray) >= 100:
        tarray[-100].join()
```

How does this perform? If something is wrong, tell me.

Comment: noofthreads = 100  same thing happens.. (memory increasing gradually)