# Growing Buffer error using lxml in Python

Tags: python, memory, lxml

while i am parsing a html document using lxml.. its giving me the following error

internal Buffer error : Memory Allocation Failed : growing buffer
I/O error : buffer bull

and the GUi is getting crashed(AppCrash.exe) with Fault Module name lxml.etree.pyd

is there any fix for this?

```
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(htmltextofpage)
actionurl=doc.xpath("//form[contains(@id,'contact')]")[0].attrib['action']
```

program is running with multiple threads. it runs just fine for some time after that it will throw the error

Comment: I think you need to show some code. How can the problem be reproduced?

Comment: How can the problem be reproduced if you don't even show us what `htmltextofpage` is?

Comment: its the html source of webpages..you can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252292/thread-memory-usage-keeps-increasing